# Simple HTML UI boxes

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm having some trouble with some basic HTML/CSS and would like to know what I'm doing wrong or if there is a smarter way to do things?

I'm basically wanting to create a simple UI and have created this but it doesn't seem to work quite right.  Box4 or 6 seem to be misbehaving when I resize the browser window:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .box1
    {
        width:100%;
        height:25%;
        background-color:#eee;
    }
    .box2
    {
        width:60%;
        height:56%;
        background-color:#eee;
        float:left;
        margin-top:1%;
    }
    .box3
    {
        width:39%;
        height:40%;
        background-color:#eee;
        margin-left:61%;
        margin-top:1%;

    }
    .box4
    {

        width:39%;
        height:14%;
        background-color:#eee;
        margin-left:61%;
        margin-top:1%;  

    }
    .box5
    {
        width:50%;
        height:14%;
        background-color:#eee;
        float:left;
        margin-top:1%;
    }
    .box6
    {
        width:49%;
        height:14%;
        background-color:#eee;
        margin-left:51%;
        margin-top:1%;

    }


    html,body{
        height:100%;
        //width:100%;
    }
    </style>


    <div class="box1">
        box1
    </div>
    <div class="box2">
        box2
    </div>
    <div class="box3">
        box3
    </div>
    <div class="box4">
        box4
    </div>
    <div class="box5">
        box5
    </div>
    <div class="box6">
        box6
    </div>
```

Edited - added screen grab of what I see when resizing the browser window.
[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzlKf.png)

Any help please guys, much appreciated.

Slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
html,body{height:100%;}
.box1{width:100%;height:25%;background-color:#eee;}
.box2{width:60%;height:56%;background-color:#eee;}
.box3{width:39%;height:40%;background-color:#eee;}
.box4{width:39%;height:15.5%;background-color:#eee;}
.box5{width:50%;height:14%;background-color:#eee;}
.box6{width:49%;height:14%;background-color:#eee;}
body > div {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  box1
</div>
<div class="box2">
  box2
</div>
<div class="box3">
  box3
</div>
<div class="box4">
  box4
</div>
<div class="box5">
  box5
</div>
<div class="box6">
  box6
</div>
```

Comment: Tweaked this a little more, didn't realise you could do .5% etc - think its the best I'm going to get.  Myself and my OCD thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working alright here. Perhaps you could be more clear about the problem?

```css
html,body{height:100%;/*width:100%;*/}
.box1{width:100%;height:25%;background-color:#eee;}
.box2{width:60%;height:56%;background-color:#eee;float:left;margin-top:1%;}
.box3{width:39%;height:40%;background-color:#eee;margin-left:61%;margin-top:1%;}
.box4{width:39%;height:14%;background-color:#eee;margin-left:61%;margin-top:1%;}
.box5{width:50%;height:14%;background-color:#eee;float:left;margin-top:1%;}
.box6{width:49%;height:14%;background-color:#eee;margin-left:51%;margin-top:1%;}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  box1
</div>
<div class="box2">
  box2
</div>
<div class="box3">
  box3
</div>
<div class="box4">
  box4
</div>
<div class="box5">
  box5
</div>
<div class="box6">
  box6
</div>
```

Comment: When I resize the browser window boxes4 and 6 seem to go out sync.  They don't sit correctly within the rest of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the total sum of the height %? It seems that box 2 has a height of 56%  but box 3 and box 4 have a total of 55% (including the margin of 1%).